# Restriction for maximum number of python modules in Google App Engine paid app

Tags: google-app-engine

From [this page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/#Python_Limits) it says that the maximum number of python modules per App for Google App Engine paid app is 20. But I am having a hard time understanding this kind of a limitation imposed on the number of python modules. In fact I can't believe that they would put a restriction like this.

For a fairly large and complex application one could easily and quickly exceed 20 python modules if one uses a modular approach and creates several highly cohesive python modules with each one of they doing their job well. In that case does it mean that one would have to forcibly stuff in more code into each python module to keep the number of modules within 20?

So I guess the questions comes down to

- Why would they put such a restriction?
- How would it affect a large scale application?
- Such a restriction doesn't make sense to me and gives me second thoughts about using GAE. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the alert. I have fixed it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page is talking about App Engine Modules, and not about Python modules. App Engine Modules are logic pieces of the app that can be served on different subdomains and use different code base but share DB, memcache and other resources.

This is **not a restriction on Python modules** you would use with statements like `import some_module`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I had completely made the wrong interpretation of "App Engine Modules in Python", since I was only familiar with python modules.